# Command "drush vset maintenance_mode 1" gives me an error

Tags: drush

Issuing the command

```
drush vset maintenance_mode 1
```

gives me an error:

> Deprecated function: Array and string offset access syntax with curly[error] braces is deprecated in include_once() (line 20 of /usr/share/drupal/includes/file.phar.inc).

I am wondering if I have to upgrade drush for getting rid of that error. I tried anyway to issue:

```
drush dl drush
```

At the prompt, I gave 1 as answer. I got next output. Again errors, even if it outputs `[success]` at the end.

```
There are no stable releases for project drush.                      [warning]
Choose one of the available releases for drush:
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
 [0]  :  Cancel                                      
 [1]  :  8.x-6.x-dev  -  2013-Sep-30  -  Development
1
Unable to extract                                                    [error]
/tmp/drush_tmp_1603203813_5f8ef2e5117e3/drush-8.x-6.x-dev.tar.gz_date=1380571116.
Unknown archive format.
Project drush (8.x-6.x-dev) downloaded to /home/pf/drush.            [success]
Project drush contains 0 modules: .
```

I am a little bit stuck since everything I try is going wrong. A little help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What php version are you running? Seems like php 7.4?

Comment: Indeed: `PHP 7.4.3`.

Comment: `drush dl drush` probably isn't giving you the latest 8.x version since it's moved to github/composer. Try downloading drush 8 directly from github: https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases/tag/8.4.5

Comment: @Demerit I wonder if there is any relationship between the version of drush (8 in this case) and the version of Drupal (which is 7 in my case). I would like to know if it is allowed to use drush 8 with Drupal 7?

Comment: Yes you can mix versions a bit. https://www.drush.org/install/#drupal-compatibility